# Passing data from one component to another - React & Redux

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I've created a login page, where I'm using `axios.get` to retrieve information about a user from an AWS SQL database. Once retrieving this information, I would like to pass the user ID to an Analytics page. I'm building all of this on React.

I'm using `redux` to do this, but I'm having an issue with setting the userID inside the login page after getting the information from AWS. Here's how I'm getting the information from AWS and trying to dispatch this new userID into the redux store.

```
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { setUserId } from '../redux/methods.js'

      axios.get(url+this.state.email)
        .then(res => {
          let userid = res.data.result.ID; //The user ID is in res.data.result.ID
          this.props.dispatch(setUserId(userid));
        })

export default connect()(Login)
```

But this does not change the userID inside the redux store. So when I'm accessing the value inside the analytics page, I'm still getting the default state.

Here is my `redux` code

The reducer

```
const userIdDefaultState = {
  id: 0
};

export default (state = userIdDefaultState, action) => {

  switch (action.type){

    case 'SET_USER_ID':
    return action.id;

    default:
      return state;

  }
};
```

Set User ID Method

```
export const setUserId = (id = '') => ({
  type: 'SET_USER_ID',
  id
});
```

This is how I'm getting the data from the redux store inside the analytics page

```
let userID = this.props.id;
```

This is rendering the default information I'm providing inside the store, so I'm guessing it's the setUserId method that's not working.

Inside index.js, I tried this and it dispatches the information to the store correctly so I'm not sure why it isn't working inside of login.

```
store.dispatch(setUserId({ id: 2}));
```

Any tips would be very much appreciated. Thank you! :)

Answer (score 1):

In your reducer,

```
case 'SET_USER_ID':
    return action.id;
```

the statement `return action.id` will override the entire `userIdDefaultState` and it doesn't match your payload.

Given that your state structure contains `id` key, you just have to ensure that the reducer is only updating that part.

```
export const setUserId = (id = '') => ({
  type: 'SET_USER_ID',
  payload: id // added payload key
});

export default (state = userIdDefaultState, action) => {
  const payload = action.payload;

  switch (action.type){
    case 'SET_USER_ID':
      return { ...state, id: payload } // payload is the id
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you - but this makes the id undefined? So now, when I'm trying to access the variable inside of Analytics, this gives me an error..

Comment: You're welcome! your dispatch should look like this: `store.dispatch(setUserId(2));`.

Answer (score 0):

```
switch (action.type){

    case 'SET_USER_ID':
    return {...state, id: action.id};

    default:
      return state;

  }
```

Comment: Still no luck... Thank you though :)